# Power Automate Rejecting JSON Data Because of Missing Array?

Tags: arrays, json, power-automate

I am working with a 3rd party system, and they sent me this sample Json which contains 2 items:-

```
{"OOH.12m2.2024.3.520":{"Brand":"test","OOH_price_list":{"Net_Total":"23332.500","Grand_Total":"27065.700","Sales_Tax":"16.00","Total":"27450.000","DIscount":"15.00"},"BR_price_list":{"Net_Total":"280.000","Grand_Total":"324.800","Amount_In_Words":"Three Hundred Twenty Four and Eight Hundred  Fils Only","Sales_Tax":"16.00"},"OOH_media_list":[{"Network":"Select A","Amount":"15000.000","Duration":"2 week","of_Faces":"15","Start_Date":"04-Mar-2024","End_Date":"17-Mar-2024","Delivery Date":"04-Mar-2024"},{"Network":"Amman Select A","Amount":"15000.000","Duration":"2 week","of_Faces":"15","Start_Date":"04-Mar-2024","End_Date":"17-Mar-2024","Delivery Date":"04-Mar-2024"}],"Sales Person Email":"****@gmail.com","blue_river_list":[{"Network":"Select / Static A","Amount":"280.000","Cost_Face":"35.000","of_Faces":"8","Start_Date":"04-Mar-2024"}],"Contract Number":"OOH.12m2.2024.3.520","Client Name":"test","Sector":"AUDIO,VIDEO & PHOTO EQUIPMENTS","No of Faces":"98","Sales Person Name":"********\t"},"OOH.12m2.2024.3.525":{"Brand":"Test - Asad","Sales Person Email":"it@****.com","Contract Number":"OOH.12m2.2024.3.525","Client Name":"test asad","Sector":"AUTOMOTIVE","No of Faces":"0","Sales Person Name":"****"}}
```

Here is the Json in Json viewer:-

[image]

Now I'm thinking that the Json is not valid for me to parse, as the first item and the second item do not have the same Json structure/schema. Am I correct? For example, if the second item does not have `OOH_price_list` then should it not show as an empty array (`"OOH_price_list": []`) instead of not showing at all? Am I correct?

Comment: Rejecting json how? Show us the error.

Comment: @Skin the error is inside power automate that it cannot find the missing properties on the second item

Comment: That doesn’t help, show us the exact error, I.e. a screenshot or something. Also, show us your schema that’s it’s validating the json against.

Answer (score 1):

No, there's nothing invalid about that JSON data on its face. JSON object members don't need to be present when they have an empty value. In your case the first item in the array has values for `OOH_Price_List` etc. while the second simply doesn't. This should deserialize fine in any major language including Javascript.

Sometimes this is expressly done to reduce the amount of data going across the network. In C# for example (using Newtonsoft JSON.NET) you can use a decorator `[JsonProperty(DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore)]` which causes the serialized JSON to entirely omit members which are `null` or even when numbers are 0. (This can actually lead to problems in Javascript because the numbers will deserialize as `undefined` which `!== 0`!)

Comment: i am using power automate to get the json and parse, on the second item i am getting errors that the array is not present

Comment: @microsoftdeveloperdesigner ah I see. Well I'm afraid all I can say is that it should not be rejecting it unless the array is actually required data for some substantive reason. But just as a matter of syntax it's valid JSON. If you deserialized that to C# or Javascript or any other language I know of those array members would just be interpreted as `null`.

Comment: @microsoftdeveloperdesigner I made some edits to your question including adding the powerautomate tag which might attract some more expert attention. Maybe there's something about that platform in particular going on.